# Removing line with common pattern from one file and adding it to another

Tags: csh, tcsh

I have a series of list files each of which contain a list of filenames.
I would like to loop through each of these list files and if one (or more) of its filenames contain a certain common pattern at a given location in the filename I would like to remove it from one of the list files into the other (doesnt matter which list file into which list file).
Have to do it in tcsh.
For example lets say I have the following 3 list files

file 1:

```
abcdefg.ext
nyrtsed.ext
sapoltw.ext
```

file 2:

```
rncdefg.ext
nydusap.ext
```

file 3:

```
revflon.ext
tradefg.ext
```

and I am looking at the substring from chars 3-6 (0 based)
then the filename `abcdefg.ext` in file 1, has the same substring as the filename `rncdefg.ext` in file 2 and the same substring as the filename `tradefg.ext` in file 3.
I would like to move those 3 filenames all to the same list file (either file 1, 2 or 3).

So if I moved them all to file 3 I would end up with

file 1:

```
nyrtsed.ext
sapoltw.ext
```

file 2:

```
nydusap.ext
```

file 3:

```
revflon.ext
tradefg.ext
abcdefg.ext
rncdefg.ext
```

This is my first trial (still incomplete) but seems to me to be too complicated (lots of nested for loops)

```
foreach list1 ($lists)
  foreach file1 ( `cat ${list}`)
    set pat1=`basename $file1 | cut -c10-14`
    foreach list2 ($lists)
       if ($list1 != $list2) then
          foreach file2 ( `cat ${list2}`)
             set pat2=`basename $file2 | cut -c10-14`
             if ( $pat1 == $pat2 ) then
                # have to remove from list1 and add it to list2
                # how to?
             endif
          end
       endif
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried? And why if you `"Have to do it in tcsh"` have you included the [bash] tag? Add your efforts to your question so we know where you are stuck.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I updated the question with a partial trial. The bash tag is because in the past I have been able to convert a solution in bash to tcsh. Since solutions in bash are more common it makes sense to ask a wider community. Particularly since this is not an easy question. On a related note I find comments like yours pompous and not very useful. If you dont have constructive comments/hints to a question,  use your time better in other questions. Unless you post these kind of comments for the upvotes.